# How to extract WebElements using linkText from fields and click on it

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, extract, gettext

I would like to catch a text within the field and be able to click on that element. It extracts all the elements' texts into log when I use the following:

```
 String text;
 text = HomePageFields.TableOneColumn(driver).getText();
System.out.println("Table One Column contains following:\n" + text);
```

The `TableOneColumn` `xpath` is on different class:

```
public static WebElement TableOneColumn(WebDriver driver) throws IOException {
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@eventproxy,'isc_QMetricsView_0')]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[contains(@style,'position')]/div"));
    return element;
```

I tried to use:

```
HomePageFields.TableOneColumn(driver).findElement(By.linkText("RFI Overview")).click();
```

But it gives an error saying won't find the element.

Here is the html link to that particular text. But other text contain in the same tag but different locations within that main tag.

[image: HTML path]

Comment: Please share the url of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[.='RFI Overview']")).click();
```

I'd suggest using the div with id isc_3BL as well, but I am not certain that is a static id. If it is, you could definitely use it to isolate from any other outside table containing the same exact td with text "RFI Overview"

Comment: Sir, you are awesome! It worked perfectly. I do have one more question, but not related to this topic. My action classes don't work. I have searched for the answer, but I can't find it. It throws an error saying "UnsupportedCommandException: //...../moveto did not match a known command.

Comment: I don't know how to answer this. Please post another question with code. Don't forget to include your imports, as that is important to know if you are using the write libraries

Answer (score 1):

Actually [`By.linkText()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html#linkText-java.lang.String-) locates `<a>` elements by the exact text it displays while **desire text is not inside any `<a>` tag**. That's why you're in trouble.

You should try using [`By.xpath()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html#xpath-java.lang.String-) with this text as below :-

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[descendant::td[text() = 'RFI Overview']]"));
System.out.println("Table One Column contains following:\n" + el.getText());
el.click();
```

Or

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[normalize-space(.) = 'RFI Overview']"));
System.out.println("Table One Column contains following:\n" + el.getText());
el.click();
```

Or As I'm seeing in provided screenshot desire `<div>` has `id` attribute which value looks like unique. If this attribute value is fixed for this element, you can also try using [`By.id()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html#id-java.lang.String-) as :-

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.id("isc_3BL"));
System.out.println("Table One Column contains following:\n" + el.getText());
el.click();
```